# Is it possible to install pure Android on any Android phone?

Tags: rom-flashing, vanilla-android

As the title says, is it possible? What is AOSP (Android Open Source Project)? I want to install a pure Android operating system, nothing else. Full control (root access), no bloatware and all.

Is there any possible way, as Android is said to be an open source, so why we are bounded by these restrictions?

Comment: And please, DO NOT SCREAM. My eyes are hurt … As for your goal: that's called a [custom ROM](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/custom-roms/info).

Comment: [Here](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=aosp+rom+for+android+devices) is your answer.

Comment: @Firelord, sorry for plagiarizing your ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Depends whether there is a ROM of the kind you are looking for available for your device. AOSP is simply Google's source code for pure stock android, with no modifications whatsoever.